# Is this phrase non-restrictive?

Tags: clauses

Would the phrase, "*trying to find sea shells*," be non-restrictive, and should it take a comma before it in the sentence, "*I'm currently at this lake, trying to find sea shells, but instead, I found this dollar bill*"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distinction between restrictive and non-restrictive modifiers applies to *direct* modifiers.   The modifier in question isn't direct.   It's a complement.   One way or another, "trying to find sea shells" is governed by the verb "am".

One possibility is that "at the lake" (with or without the "currently") and "trying to find sea shells" are asyndeticly coordinated complements.   If so, the comma in question replaces the coordinating conjunction: "I'm currently at this lake *and* trying to find sea shells."   Without the comma, an asyndetic interpretation isn't available.

Another possibility is that "at the lake" is an adjunct or part of an adjunct instead of an argument.   If so, its relationship to the verb "am" is separate from the argument's, and no comma is warranted.   This set of relationships might be easier to see if we remove "at the lake" and let "currently" stand as the only adjunct: "I'm currently trying to find sea shells."

Whether the comma belongs has nothing to do with the phrase "trying to find sea shells".   The role of the phrase "at the lake" determines whether a comma in that location is warranted.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the first comma in this sentence.

> I'm currently at this lake trying to find sea shells, but instead, I found this dollar bill

"trying to find seashells" could be non-restrictive, but in this sentence it seems like it is restrictive, since you say, "but instead". "Trying to find seashells" is the focus of the first half of the sentence, since it is the target of "but instead".

An example where "trying to find seashells" is non-restrictive:

> I was at the lake, trying to find sea shells, when I found a dollar bill.

Comment: Wouldn't a comma go after "instead"? Also, if everything else was removed after "trying to find sea shell," then it'll be non-restrictive, right?

Comment: Yes, you are right about the comma. Actually in the process I found this eerily similar question: https://www.grammarly.com/answers/questions/88243-do-commas-go-around-but-instead/

Comment: Am I right about that there's a comma before "looking for sea shells" when nothing is after that phrase?

Comment: I'm not totally sure. I think it depends somewhat. Is "looking for sea shells" extra information or crucial information? I don't think it's obviously either.

Comment: For example, "singing the whole way" is a non-restrictive clause in the sentence, "We drove four hours today, singing the whole way". But, "having fun" seems like a restrictive clause in the sentence, "I'm at the park having fun".

Comment: It's not eerily similar, it's _entirely_ similar. "Tim" (ELL) and "Brian" (Grammerly) are the same person, I believe.

Comment: The phrasing was a bit different, and that was 11 days ago. Maybe students in the same class, or using the same workbook?

Comment: A relative clause is ***restrictive*** if it's semantically necessary in order to unambiguously identify the ***specific*** subject it references. Since it's logically impossible for ***I*** to be an ambiguous reference, there's no way "trying to find seashells" could be a restrictive clause narrowing us down to that particular ***I***. A structurally similar version that really is restrictive would be, for example, *My son studying at Oxford will be home for Xmas [but my other son who's at Cambridge won't be coming back this year].*

Comment: To me, "looking for seashells" is more clearly restrictive in this sentence: "*I am walking around a lake, looking for seashells*", but it doesn't seem the same in the sentence, "*I am at a lake looking for seashells*". I think you're right, though, so should I remove my answer?

Comment: And what about the same sentence, rearranged: "*I am looking for seashells at a lake*." Is "*at a lake*" now a non-restrictive clause, or does "*looking for seashells at a lake*" form one clause?